# get the name of the group inside pandas groupby transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here is what I am trying to do. I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_cols = 3
n_samples = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n_samples * n_cols).reshape(n_samples, n_cols), columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A   B   C
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

I have a category to which each sample (row) belongs:

```
cat = pd.Series([1,1,2,2])
```

And I have a reference row related to each category:

```
df_ref = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2, n_cols)), index=[1,2], columns=list('ABC'))
df_ref.loc[1] = 10
print(df_ref)
```

output:

```
      A     B     C
1  10.0  10.0  10.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

How do I do the following in a more elegant way (e.g., using groupby and transform):

```
result = df.copy()
for i in range(n_cols):
  result.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i] - df_ref.loc[cat[i]]
print(results)
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0 -10  -9  -8
1  -7  -6  -5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
```

I thought something like this should work:

```
df.groupby(cat).transform(lambda x: x - df_ref.loc[x.GROUP_NAME])
```

where x.GROUP_NAME is accessing the name of the group on which transform is operating. In the [pandas documentation about transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform) it is written: "Each group is endowed the attribute ‘name’ in case you need to know which group you are working on." I tried to access x.name, but that gives the name of a column, not the name of the group. So I don't understand what this documentation is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `grouby`, just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df_ref` and convert to array:

```
df -= df_ref.reindex(cat).values
```

Or, for a copy:

```
out = df.sub(df_ref.reindex(cat).values)
```

Note that your approach would work with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = df.groupby(cat, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x - df_ref.loc[x.name])
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0
1  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0
2   6.0   7.0   8.0
3   9.0  10.0  11.0
```

Comment: "*Each group is endowed the attribute ‘name’ in case you need to know which group you are working on.*" -> in `transform` `.name` actually refers to the column name. The documentation might be incorrect.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much! I didn't think of this more direct approach. As an alternative, one can also simply use loc instead of reindex.

Comment: ok, thanks. I am still a bit confused why this works with apply and not with transform...

Comment: @Chachni if you're sure the indices exist, yes `loc` will also work

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
df = df.set_index(cat)
df = df - df_ref

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      A     B     C
1 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0
1  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0
2   6.0   7.0   8.0
2   9.0  10.0  11.0
```